# how to check new files added on my svn?

Tags: linux, svn

I created a svn server... so, I created my repo with `svnadmin create mycode` ... then I made a copy of it making a `svn checkout` ... later I created some folders and then I did another checkout.. it worked fine, so from other computer I made a checkout and I got the folders, just like they were...

the problem is when I added folder from my client (another computer) and I did a checkout... It worked fine, and if Icheckout from another (a 3rd) computer, I get the last changes made, incluided the added folders.

So, I thought from my first copy, the copy I have on my server I should be able to get all the changes only with an update command, still , I get ". omited" , any idea?

if use the command `svn update`

Thanks

Comment: can you include a sequence of commands and which computers you ran them on? It's a bit hard to follow exactly what happened here.

Comment: It seems that you are running `svn update` in a non-SVN folder. Try to `cd` to the root of your working copy first...

Comment: Perhaps you have worked in the past with Git, and are used that the checkout location is a copy of the repository (which is not). And the repository itself is not a working copy. So you cannot work with the files where you have created your repository. Could you explain what "first copy" is?

Comment: I was in my root's working copy, when I try in a folder that is not the message is "folder" is not a working copy. I am running it on debian squeeze. For the checkout (at my server) I used svn checkout file:///repository_name/project project

Comment: my "first copy" I was talking about the checkout I did from my server, to be able to manage all from there.